# Adding user group to organization for liferay

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6, portal

I would like to configure my liferay portal to use User Groups and for those groups to belong to an organization.  I am using a hook to create users and when I tried to add the user I got the following error.

```
15:12:07,991 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-1740][AutoLogin:127] Exception message = No Group exists with the key {companyId=10157, name=UserGroup} cause = null
```

I followed the two following articles.

The first article says how to make the portal-ext.properties file.  The second article says to add `organizations.user.group.membership.enabled=true` to the portal-ext.properties file. After doing both of these I restarted Tomcat. However I have no idea where to go to add the user group to the organization.  Any ideas?

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/3467725

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12709699

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late but it appears this functionality was removed in Liferay 6.1. See Jorge's comments in the following thread. Jorge mentions some alternatives depending on what your use case is.

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14333511